# Android Bottom sheet logs elapse time when expanded

Tags: android, mapbox, bottom-sheet

I have a map and bottom sheet in my app. When bottom sheet is collapsed, everything is ok, but if i expand it, in my log pereodically appears message about elapse time.

```
06-03 10:17:51.391 25789-26054/com.example.pici.mapboxtest W/MALI: glDrawArrays:714: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 6213
06-03 10:17:58.344 25789-26054/com.example.pici.mapboxtest W/MALI: glDrawArrays:714: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 5026
06-03 10:18:01.373 25789-26054/com.example.pici.mapboxtest W/MALI: glDrawArrays:714: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 5347
06-03 10:18:05.268 25789-26054/com.example.pici.mapboxtest W/MALI: glDrawArrays:714: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 5434
06-03 10:18:15.158 25789-26054/com.example.pici.mapboxtest W/MALI: glDrawArrays:714: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 11730
06-03 10:18:18.155 25789-26054/com.example.pici.mapboxtest W/MALI: glDrawArrays:714: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 8915
```

What is the problem about my app?

Answer (score 0):

I think its normal. I have this warning in blank app if first run app.

```
glDrawArrays:714: [MALI] glDrawArrays takes more than 5ms here. Total elapse time(us): 8248
```

**glDrawArrays** - draw line by dots. If u have many dots(advanced grafics) u have this warnings.

**Its normal.**